# Formatting <select> borders

Tags: html, css

I need to add a border to a `<select>` element, but I want to overlap the border generally provided by the button to the right (so it doesn't look totally despicable: <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub>). It should be a CSS-only solution since this will be used for all `<select>` elements in my website. If absolutely necessary I can leave the `<select>` elements unstyled and they'll just look slightly different from everything else in forms. Anyways, onto the solutions I have tried...

### Attempt #1

My first solution was to use `outline`. This has minimal side effects (since it doesn't change the sizing) and goes on top of everything (which is what I want). It's supported by IE8, but in order to get it to overlap the content of the element, I need to use `outline-offset`. Unfortunately, this is new in the CSS3 spec so it's not supported by IE at all.

Here is what that looked like: http://jsfiddle.net/9w9et7fp/

### Attempt #2

My next solution was to use `box-shadow`. This lets you set a shadow for your element. By default, this is on the outside of your element. However you can specify to make it `inset`, which is exactly what I'm looking for. While this is more IE-friendly, it isn't supported by IE8.

Here is what that looked like: http://jsfiddle.net/9w9et7fp/1/

### A new hope?

I've searched around enough and have run out of ideas. I could probably get a workaround by using HTML, having a fixed-sized container element with `overflow: hidden` so that I can emulate a border. But that would mean I would have to do it for every `<select>` in my website. Perhaps someone knows of a different solution that can do what I'm looking for? Even an IE-only filter would be fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a modification from my first attempt for a compromise. I made the border to be one pixel wide and set the `outline-offset` to -2 pixels. In IE that leaves a small space between the outline and the button that looks acceptable to me. In Firefox and other browsers, it looks as I originally intended.

There is a downside: when there's a background that's not white, I have to choose whether to leave a white border around the `<select>` elements for most browsers or have the border the same color as the background and make it clear that the outline isn't attached to the `<select>` in IE.

See the jsFiddle I made to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/9w9et7fp/6/

Answer (score 0):

Select element style support is pretty limited, as you've discovered. I've seen/done the container method before. Is there any reason you couldn't use a JS solution, though? as far as I can tell, it would meet your requirement of affecting all select elements sitewide. There are a handful of form elements "enhancers" out there. I've used both of these.

http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: The reason I didn't want to go with a JS solution is that it means I'm not using standard browser APIs for something that's common throughout my site. This requires that I modify all code applied to `<select>` elements (especially event handlers) and makes it more difficult for future developers to work with (it's not straightforward and more convoluted).